# elements with background-attachment: fixed don't behave same on mobile as on desktop

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, cross-browser, mobile-safari

Seems like this issue is known for few years already. 
I tried to apply blurred background to inside elements with class "`.blurred-bg`" as per this example https://codepen.io/ariona/pen/geFIK . It has one clear-version image applied as background of body element and blurred-version of same image is applied to elements with class `.blurred-bg`.

**Here is my code** do you know, what can I try to make it work?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>blurred background sablona</title>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;                
                background-image: url("https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-3eBjuQpOGFw/U47yh_-OycI/AAAAAAAAI2U/uaU5pK49N1w/s1600/normal.jpg");
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
                background-attachment: fixed;
            }
            
            .blurred-bg {
                background-image: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-m8TxQMObg6c/U474EWu7Y9I/AAAAAAAAI2k/xkRGoIEC1iU/s1600/blur.jpg");
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
                    -moz-background-size: cover;
                    -o-background-size: cover;
                    -webkit-background-size: cover;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }
            
            
            #centered_div {background: red;padding: 10px; text-align: center;color: white}
            .LISTS_CONTAINER{
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                overflow-x: auto;
                justify-content: center;
            }
            .LIST_WRAPPER {
                margin: 20px;
                box-shadow: 
                    0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 
                    0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 
                    0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                box-sizing: border-box;
                width:; /* width cannot be set, because this div needs to adjust to its content*/
                height:; /* height cannot be set, because this div needs to adjust to its content*/
            }
            .LIST{
                grid-gap: 0px;
                width: 400px;
                height: 305px;
                position: relative; /* this needs to stay relative */
                background: rgba(0,0,0,); /*change opacity to make div darker*/
                border-radius: 10px;
                color: white;
                font-size: 30px;
                text-align: center;
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="centered_div">
            DIVs with blurred background while you scroll.<br>On desktop Safari & Chrome it works, but on mobile the background is no more fixed.
        </div> 
        
        <div class="LISTS_CONTAINER">
            <div class="LIST_WRAPPER blurred-bg">
                <div class="LIST">scroll down</div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="LIST_WRAPPER blurred-bg">
                <div class="LIST">scroll down</div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="LIST_WRAPPER blurred-bg">
                <div class="LIST">scroll down</div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="LIST_WRAPPER blurred-bg">
                <div class="LIST">scroll down</div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="LIST_WRAPPER blurred-bg">
                <div class="LIST">scroll down</div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="LIST_WRAPPER blurred-bg">
                <div class="LIST">scroll down</div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="LIST_WRAPPER blurred-bg">
                <div class="LIST">scroll down</div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="LIST_WRAPPER blurred-bg">
                <div class="LIST">scroll down</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

## Have already tried:

**1. attempt:** using javascript by adding:

```js
    $ (window).scroll(function() {
        var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('.blurred-bg').css('background-position', 'left' + ((scrolledY)) + 'px');
    });
```

and also had to apply `background-position: left top` to styles for class `.blurred-bg` .
Tested on tablet and mobile - no success.

**2. attempt:**
Wrapped all content which is in the body in one parent wrapper, set height to 500px and overflow to auto. 
Tested on tablet and mobile - no success.

**3. attempt:** changing property from `backgroundAttachment='fixed';` to `backgroundAttachment='scroll';` also did not help.

On desktop it works nicely but on mobile browsers the effect is broken since `background-attachment: fixed;` is not supported anymore. It demands higher performance which is not good for mobile devices according to what I found online. I have found various workarounds and also many ideas on stack-overflow posts but none of them worked for me. Its already morning and i didn't make it work so maybe you guys have idea.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue. Well sadly, mobile browsers have that feature disabled because it can be too much costly for them. It works on Firefox though.